# How to Put image or image based text on Navigation tab (bar) in Oracle APEX 4?

Tags: image, tabs, oracle-apex

Got this basic issue..

I have two tab navigation bar in Oracle APEX 4.0. The parent tab and the standard tab.

The standard tab which is below parent tab starting from left, I would like to put a text or image made of text on the right side which describes the overall application.

The Text or Image of made of text will be "BASIC PROGRAM" in a Green color with big font size.

Can anybody guide me how to proceed..

I was thinking using substitution strings such as #tab_cells# may work, but not sure where to put and how to do it?

appreciate your help..

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are long due an overhaul, the customisation you can do on them is extremely limited. Short of completely overhauling your menu system, i'd alter this one tab through javascript/jquery.

Please take care with selectors for tabs. I have no idea which theme you are using, i did this for **theme 21** with 2 level tabs, selecting a 2nd level tab. Inspect your HTML and adapt this to your requirement.

```
$("ul#tabs li").each(function(){
   if($(this).text().indexOf('Maatregelen')!=-1){
      $(this).children('a.tab_link').css(
         {"background":'url()', "background-color":"green", "text-shadow":"none"}
       );
   };
});
```

I wouldn't change the template per se. There is not much you can do there to the tab generation, since you can not use plsql code. Rather, you could put the tab label in an attribute on a higher level than the a-tag, to have an easier jquery selector. Or you can put the javascript code in to run on-load. Or have a dynamic action on page zero to run on-load, and this will affect every tab in each page.